# move term-description woocommerce below product

Tags: php, css, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I have one issue with term-description text Currently is placed on top of product category, and i want to place it at bottom after products. I have implemented the above code. but after I checked it worked in the wocommerce category but didn't work in the sub category. the display of sub categories

i have tried using this code. it works only in the wocoomer category it doesn't work in subcategories

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVsfW.png)

```
add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'custom_archive_description', 2 );
function custom_archive_description(){
    if( is_product_category() ) :
        remove_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 5 );
    endif;
}
```

Comment: This question would be more appropriately asked on the [WordPress Development site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code on **function.php**

```
// Archive Product - Description Below Products
add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'custom_archive_description', 2 );
function custom_archive_description(){
    if( is_product_category() ) :
        remove_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 5 );
    endif;
}
```